# Open Database Schema in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: .net, database-schema, visual-studio-2013

I have already spent couple hours for that trying to find by myself, but no luck so far...

I need to open my db table in schema view so I can add relationships for my tables.

This is what I have now :

[image]

This is how it used to be in old visual studio:

[image]

this is what I need to get: [image]

Thanks everyone in advance !

Comment: Missing information: the schemas are not visible in the question.

Comment: What version of VS2013 do you have, Pro, Ultimate?

Comment: @Stanislav did you find either of the answers helpful? If not, can you provide more details about your setup.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Connect to the server via **Server Explorer** then navigate to the table that will be used as the **foreign key**. Right click and select **Open Table Definition**.

[image]

Once it's loaded, go to **View** -> **Toolbars** -> **Table Designer** and click it if it isn't already checked.

Next, click on the **Relationships** icon

[image]

From there use the following links for more information on using the relationship tool.

[How to: Create Relationships Between Tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zed0k41d.aspx)

[Foreign Key Relationships Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54eyz5bs.aspx)

**Note: These options were not available in VS2013 SKU's Pro and Express (for me). Premium and Ultimate had them. VS2012 Pro had them available.**

Comment: I have the same problem as the OP, except for me, after I enabled the table designer buttons, they remain disabled no matter which table I open via 'open table definition'.

Answer (score 2):

Select the Database file (*.mdf or *.sdf) in **Solution Manager** then double click the database file. The **Server Explorer** is opened database connection. Then till down the database and tables to see the tables. Finally select table then Right click and select **Open Table Definition.**

Refer the above post image....

In this Server Explorer you can see the Database and it's Schema. Schema is like tables, views, stored procedures, etc...

Also you can change the table and its contents. You can Alter Table Columns, Add Tables and Insert Table Records and Update Table Records, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a designer file (.edmx) from your existing db. Assuming you used "code first" to create your db,

1 - go to your model folder

2 - right click -> Add - > New Item

3 - Select "ADO NET Entity Data Model"

4 - Select "EF Designer from Database"

[image: Add Diagram to DB Model]

5- And you have your diagram!