# How to view data of a table in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: database, visual-studio-2013

How to show data of a table in Visual studio 2013. As it shows in Visual studio 2008 as shown in the image!. The image is of Visual studio 2008 which is showing data of a table. Like wise I want to see data of a table in Visual studio 2013

[image: picture]

Answer (score 2):

It's just right click on the table in your Database Schema in Server Explorer then choose Show Table Data.

Answer (score 0):

[Open Database Schema in Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19649547/open-database-schema-in-visual-studio-2013)
Here is an answer.

I think you are looking for that, it is really hard to know from your question.